# In Python how can I print the element of a list if that element is present in a file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to identify if any elements of a list are present in a file. I then wish to print both the element and the file name. In future iterations of this, I would eventually like to run the list against multiple files in a folder to produce a list of elements and the files in which they are present.

I have the following:

```
#imports
import os
os.system('cls')

z = open('fieldnames.txt', 'r') 

f = open('TestSQL.sql', 'r')
    

for element in z.readlines():
    if element in f.read():
        print(element)
        print(f.name)
```

I am able to print the file name, but the element that was present won't print.

Apologies for any lack of clarity, I am really new to python and appreciate any guidance I can get.

Comment: So, you should learn how to debug these sorts of things by yourself. In Python, you should fire up your REPL and try out some of the things you are doing and see if they are giving you the expected result. For example, `lines = z.readlines()`, then see what is actually inside that list... also, do `f.read()` multiple times... what happens?

Comment: After calling `f.read()` once, the file contents are exhausted.  All further calls to `f.read()` will return an empty string.  So `if element in f.read()` will true at most once.

Answer (score 1):

Just read fieldnames.txt first at once and then use it to find elements:

```
    with open('fieldnames.txt', 'r') as f:
        fieldnames = f.read()
    
    with open('TestSQL.sql', 'r') as f:
        for element in z.readlines():
            if element in fieldnames:
                print("{} {}".format(element, f.name))
```